# Custom membershiprovider validating succesfull but unable to GetUser()

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-membership

Hello fellow Stackoverflow users,

I'm currently diving into WCF a bit and i've currently setup a POC webservice which uses clientCredentialType="UserName". Since we some unique wishes we opted for a custom membershipprovider. I am currently implementing one piece by piece. This means that most methods (which aren't used yet) throw not implemented exceptions.

The methods implemented are the Initialize() and ValidateUser() methods, the validate user works, when given the right credentials a person is validate, when i enter bogus they get a security exception.

So far so good.

How ever when i call the GetUser() method (which fetched the username from somewhere and then calls):

```
public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

As you can see, this is not Implemented (so obviously, it does not work), what frustrates me at the moment is that i can't get this to work because the username which is passed from the underlaying GetUser() method (from the base class MembershipProvider) passes an empty string.

Is there something specific which i'm forgetting? Has anyone else got experience with a custom membershipprovider which tackled this issue?

Edit: added the callstack

> at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(String username, Boolean
>   userIsOnline)    at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser()    at
>   DirectPay.WCF.Services.Service.TestConnection() in D:\Projects\IBS
>   projects\DirectPay\source\WCF.Services\Service.svc.cs:line 21    at
>   SyncInvokeTestConnection(Object , Object[] , Object[] )    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)

Comment: How are you calling the `GetUser` method ? Can you post the call stack leading up to the call to this method ?

Comment: Here is the callstack (i hope this is what you mean, i'm not a debugging star :x)

Comment: No, i did not since this is not an abstract method, it's a method actually implemented withint MembershipProvider. I would expect with the logic which actually fetches the username from... the context? This is kinda where i'm stuck, i feel i need to set the username somewhere when validation... but i have no idea where to set it so GetUser() will be able to fetch it >.<

Comment: Okay, i've found a way to fetch the Name within the TestConnection method which i'm calling: ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name works. Now i still don't get why GetUser() does not though... So i'm leaving it open. Ideally i dont want my methods to bother with usernames and things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my current answer after beating my head against a wall for a few hours (most likely because i dont know jack about WCF yet ^^) is finding out you can get the current user with:

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
```

The GetUser() method sadly, still does not what i would like, a work around would be to override this method in my custom membershipprovider and fetch the name there. Another option would be to add the following to the GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline) method:

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
{
   username = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
}
```

I would love to find a way without having to fetch the Username manually, so i won't mark this as an answer as of your, if anything it's a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The user is generally supposed to be stored in a custom database of your own which is the point of implementing a custom membership provider. Here is my implementation of the same function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets information from the data source for a user.
/// Provides an option to update the last-activity date/time stamp for the user.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="username">The name of the user to get information for.</param>
/// <param name="userIsOnline">true to update the last-activity date/time 
/// stamp for the user; false to return user information without updating 
/// the last-activity date/time stamp for the user.</param>
/// <returns>A MembershipUser object populated with the specified
/// user's information from the data source.</returns>
public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
{
    // Get User from my custom database
    User user = Database.User.GetUser(username);

    // Convert User to MebmershipUser (or return null if User == null)
    return user == null ? null : new MembershipUser(
        "CustomMembershipProvider",
        user.UserName, 
        user.UserID,
        user.Email,
        string.Empty, 
        user.Comments, 
        user.Active,
        false, 
        user.CreatedDate, 
        user.LastLoginDate, 
        DateTime.Now, 
        user.LastPasswordChangedDate, 
        DateTime.Now);
}
```

Comment: Yes, i gues i wasn't clear enough. The method isn't implemented yet, simply because i wanted to get the Username first. Found the GetUser() method which did not require any Username so checked what username was passed in the end. When we used the SqlMembershipProvider Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name would return the username, currently this is also a string.Empty. Same applies for what is passed into this method. Basically i could write all the implementation i'd like in this method but it would do me no good since i don't get the correct username (or any at all).

Comment: Generally, it will be `User.Identity.Name` passed as the `username`. If you have a custom database then get that user and return it. If you're just getting the user from an ASP.Net User database then what's your reason for implementing a custom MembershipProvider?

Comment: We have a custom DB, we have to get this user based on a name though. Problem is that currently the GetUser() does NOT get a name passed to it. Eventhough the call has been validated, i feel like maybe i need to set something during validation. Or fetch the name of the current request which has been validated, as i've done in the past through Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.

Comment: @F.B. ten Kate, What's calling the function?

Comment: a method called: public string TestConnection() which is exposed as a WCF Service [OperationContract]. The whole validation is done of every call in a wsHttpBinding endpoint as i've been reading and the call is succesfully validated, but that's where things end.

Comment: Then you need to pass a valid username to test with. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think so, i am passing a valid username to test with, the validation method get's called and this works like a charm. At this point however, the method needs to somehow know what user it's currently catering. I have currently been unsuccesfull in doing so. I've got the feeling i need to set the currenprincipal or something...

Comment: This function shouldn't have to detect the user, the calling function (usually in ASP.Net) should do this.

Comment: @Chris let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2406/discussion-between-f-b-ten-kate-and-chris)